# Help - Outdoor Spearmint Has Fungus?

Tags: plant-health, fungus

the spearmint plants on my balcony seem to be suffering from some kind of ailment. They are covered in black/brown/white spots. I water them several times a week as they get a lot of direct sunlight.

Does anyone know what is troubling them?

[image: mint]
[image: diseased mint]
[image: diseased mint]
[image: diseased mint]

Comment: Are there leafhoppers on the undersides of the leaves? (They may fly when disturbed.)